# How to save two different users in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

My case is related to a purchase, the customer who buys something and the seller who sold it.

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class buy(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    seller   = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I am aware that the above code is wrong, I write it that way so the question is understood.

I take the django.contrib authentication system, to avoid having to make another authentication system for clients and one for sellers, I want django code reuse.

A solution had thought of creating another data model to sellers or customers, but in my view and in the login I'm using django.contrib, then I would still use this system authentication would like to know if there is any way or if I ultimately that create another authentication system?

Comment: So, you want to specialize users into customers or sellers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Apart from adding a related_name to those foreign keys, to avoid the reverse accessor clashing, this would work fine; what is your actual question?

Comment: I'm just guessing, if you have a Product model that has a `user` field in which case he's the actual seller, why don't you use `seller = models.ForeignKey(Product, to_field='user')`

Comment: @qasimalbaqali , About specialize users, the resulting model is cyclical, Try to relate in a class Seller and class Customer to User, but django is not related to the admin site.

Comment: @qasimalbaqali. I'll try that solution, thanks.

Comment: @qasimalbaqali. It works perfect¡ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing, if you have a Product model that has a user field in which case he's the actual seller, why don't you use `seller = models.ForeignKey(Product, to_field='user')`